# Extract custom html element attribute & content pasted in textarea using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having a textarea in which some custom html is pasted. Now I want to extract second peak hkl attribute value and its html content into other textbox. I am jQuery to do it, please have a look at my code and give me your valuable suggestions.

```js
var hkl = $('.textarea').html($("peak:eq(2).attr(hkl)"));
$('input[name="hkl2"]').val(hkl);
// output should be 0 0 2
  
var data = $('.textarea').html($("peak:eq(2)"));
$('input[name="data2"]').val(data);
// output should be 44.0%
```

```html
<textarea class='textarea'>
<Peak hkl="1 0 0" d="2.8143">57.0%</Peak>
<Peak hkl="0 0 2" d="2.6033">44.0%</Peak>
<Peak hkl="1 0 1" d="2.4759">100.0%</Peak>
</textarea>
<input name='hkl2'>
<input name='data2'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things

- create a fragment from the HTML in the textarea
- Use find to get the Peak tag
- the collection starts at 0

```js
const $peaks = $("<div/>")
  .html($('.textarea').val())
  .find("Peak");
const hkl = $peaks.eq(1).attr("hkl");
const data = $peaks.eq(1).text();
$('input[name="hkl2"]').val(hkl);
// output should be 0 0 2
 
$('input[name="data2"]').val(data);
// output should be 44.0%
```

```html
<textarea class='textarea'>
<Peak hkl="1 0 0" d="2.8143">57.0%</Peak>
<Peak hkl="0 0 2" d="2.6033">44.0%</Peak>
<Peak hkl="1 0 1" d="2.4759">100.0%</Peak>
</textarea>
<input name='hkl2'>
<input name='data2'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```